# how to propely install mAdserve?

Tags: php, mobile, ads

does anybody use mAdserve for hosting their own Ads? I wanted to install lastest version but I always got this message when I go to install.php :

```
Warning: require_once(../../init.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/u320079200/public_html/www/cp/install.php on line 10

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '../../init.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php') in /home/u320079200/public_html/www/cp/install.php on line 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Iy has to do with your file permissions! Check your permissions in the directory where the software tries to create/open a file/directory.